# Comparing CLOB using dbms_lob.compare, not geting the result I wanted

Tags: plsql

Not use to use dbms_lob.compare, so the update works fine, but when it reach the IF statement look like only do the same thing when it suppost to alternate like u can see bellow

My PL/SQL code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE teste
IS
   aux CLOB;
   cnt NUMBER := 0;
   cnt1 NUMBER := 0;      
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN (SELECT  xxxx)
     LOOP
      aux := rec.VALUE;
        UPDATE db
        SET VALUE = TO_CLOB(deletexml(
        xmltype(VALUE),
        '//*:getPaymentDetailsResponse/*:Payment/*:childs[./*:status[text()="Failed"]]'
        ))
        WHERE id=rec.gb_ID;
          --Teste
          IF DBMS_LOB.compare(rec.VALUE, aux) = 0 THEN      
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('### ORDERS NOT CHANGED ###');            
            cnt1 := cnt1 + 1;  --count orders without any change
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(cnt1 || '- ' || rec.ORDER_PUBLIC_ID);
          ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('### ORDERS CHANGED ###');
            cnt := cnt +1;  --count changed orders
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(cnt || '- ' || rec.ORDER_PUBLIC_ID);
          END IF;  
     END LOOP;
   -- Print count results
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Orders without changing: '|| cnt1 || ' orders.');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Orders updated: '|| cnt || ' orders.');
END;
/
```

This is what i am currently getting:

#### ORDERS NOT CHANGED

1- 160000

#### ORDERS NOT CHANGED

2- 160000

#### ORDERS NOT CHANGED

3- 160313

#### ORDERS NOT CHANGED

4- 160313

What I want to happen:

#### ORDERS CHANGED

1- 160000

#### ORDERS NOT CHANGED

2- 160000

#### ORDERS CHANGED

3- 160313

#### ORDERS NOT CHANGED

4- 160313

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you clarify what behaviour you are seeing, and what you expected/wanted to see?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a cursor it is a snapshot of the data as it exists at the time you run the select.  Any table changes that are made during the execution of the cursor do not get reflected in the cursor. see [Do database cursors pick up changes to the underlying data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690822/do-database-cursors-pick-up-changes-to-the-underlying-data) for more details.

So you update the base table for your cursor (I assume as you don't show the actual select)

```
UPDATE db
    SET VALUE = TO_CLOB(deletexml(
    xmltype(VALUE),
    '//*:getPaymentDetailsResponse/*:Payment/*:childs[./*:status[text()="Failed"]]'
    ))
    WHERE id=rec.gb_ID;
```

Then you do a compare using the details in your cursor

```
IF DBMS_LOB.compare(rec.VALUE, aux) = 0 THEN
```

As the cursor is a snapshot this will always come back as Not Changed, you would have to re-select the value from your base table to or use SQL%ROWCOUNT to check if your update statment affected any rows (see https://community.oracle.com/thread/2370954?start=0&tstart=0) for details of how to use this.